# I want to create a breadcrumb but i dont know how to create that in react

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-redux, breadcrumbs

this is my manage role page on which i have to display breadcrumb like manage roles/ add role
how can i do that after  in render

i want to add a breadcrumb on the top of the page 
this is a dropdown menu whose header is manage authorisers and then first option is add roles

so i want to display it like whenever my page get render

it should show like Manage Authoriser/Add role as a breadcrumb

```
                    }}
                />
                <Search with role name"
                />

                            input={{id: 'select_' + role.roleId, value: role.selected}}
                            onClick={()=> this.toggleSelect(i)}
                        />,
                        role.name?role.name:'-',
                    e: role.status === "Active" ? true : false }}
```

Comment: Hi John! Just some clarifying questions so we know how to best answer you:   
How much experience do you have with React?  
Did you write all the code above yourself?

Comment: no this is not my code but now i have to add breadcrumb in this page.
 I am new to react.

Comment: can i do like create a breadcrumb component and then call that breadcrumb component in my other files??

Comment: That is exactly what you can do. I'll post an answer.

Comment: but i need that breadcrumb in dynamic way. It wont be hard coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core thought process with React is to think in terms of reusable distinct Components. So, the first thing you would want to do is create a `<BreadCrumb />` component and work on it in isolation.

You can then use it in your Admin Page to display the breadcrumbs, passing in the props it needs to work.

If you're unsure on how to do that I'd suggest you go through the React Tutorial here: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html